# ROS Tutorial Typo

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

at the bottom of the page, the tutorials refers to

> ( export ROS_PI=machine_ip_addr)

instead of what is probably  meant to be

> ( export ROS_IP=machine_ip_addr)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318973/ros-tutorial-typo/) by [rubicj](https://answers.ros.org/users/40539/rubicj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have fixed the typo.

In the future, you can register a ROS wiki account and fix typos and other errors yourself.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2